# How can I probe an SMB share for unencrypted access?

Tags: windows, powershell, server-message-block

I am enabling SMB encryption with:

```
Set-SmbServerConfiguration -EncryptData $true -Force
```

From a monitoring service, I want to verify that only encrypted connections are accepted. How can I attempt to make a non-encrypted connection (to see it get denied)?

I have tried connecting from older Windows that doesn't support SMB3 encryption. That works, but my monitoring service runs on a recent OS.

I have considered disabling SMB3 on the machine, but that requires a reboot. I want something quick that doesn't have long-lasting side effects.

Answer (score 3):

From your monitoring server, do:

`$(Get-SmbServerConfiguration -CimSession RemoteComputer).EncryptData`

If False, then fire alert.

Comment: Yeah, that is useful... but I was hoping for a confirm that non-encrypted connections actually fail, not just a way to check that the flag is set.

Comment: You sort of already shot down all the alternatives in your original question. You don't want to turn off SMBv3, you don't want to connect from a different SMB client other than an SMBv3-enabled Windows machine... you could write your own SMB emulator I guess. :P